# prevent gradle assembleDebug to install emulator

Tags: android, gradle

I write a bash script in which my Android project will be built. I can install the `gradle` and `sdk` tools successfully. I create the wrapper with `gradle wrapper`. But when I want to get a debug apk using `./gradlew assembleDebug -x lint` it takes a long time to download the emulator:

```
Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in /build/sdk/licenses
License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 accepted.
Preparing "Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)".
"Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)" ready.
Installing SDK Patch Applier v4 in /build/sdk/patcher/v4
"Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)" complete.
"Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android Emulator in /build/sdk/licenses
License for package Android Emulator accepted.
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 32.1.12)".
```

I also run the command with `-d` and found the emulator version. Next, I download the emulator zip and extract it to the correct directory. But when I run the `assembleDebug` again, I get this warning:

```
Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v2.RemotePackage@86464c36" (emulator) should be installed in  "/usr/lib/sdk/emulator" but it already exists. Installing in "/usr/lib/sdk/emulator-2" instead.
```

I want to skip downloading the emulator (if it's available) or pass the zip file to it to prevent sticking at this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gradle wrapper automatic SDK downloads can be disabled by setting a flag in gradle.properties:

> To manually disable this feature, set android.builder.sdkDownload=false in the gradle.properties file for your project.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#download-with-gradle